# How Do I find which rows don't have at least one column marked true, grouped by another column

Tags: t-sql

I have a table for tracking PartNumber information for a Bin database. Each Bin can have many Partnumbers but at least one PartNumber must be marked as the Primary for that Bin. In my table of PartNumbers there are many records that have never been identified as being the primary and I need to be able to identify them so the data can be scrubbed before being able to enforce the business rule. I have looked at OVER(PARTION BY) but I can not figure out how to get just those records that don't have at least one PartNumber marked as primary.

Table Sturcture:

```
PartNumbnerID PK int(IDENTITY)
PartNumber varchar(20)
BinNumber char(5) FK 
BinPrimary bit
```

Sample Data:

```
PartNumberID  PartNumber    BinNumber    BinPrimary

1             123           22222          0
2             345           22222          0
3             456           33333          0
4             678           33333          0
5             789           44444          1
6             890           44444          0
```

Results of query would be:

```
BinNumber
 22222
 33333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
select BinNumber
from MyTable
group by BinNumber
having max([Primary]) = 0
```

Here's an SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1d25/2

Comment: I get this error "Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator."

Comment: Forgot to add the ampersand, I get the error above when trying your code.

Comment: @AlanFisher right, sorry about that; SQLFiddle made the field `int` by default and I didn't pay enough attention to this.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an advanage when you need more columns, however if you only need Binnumber, you should go with Wolf's solution

```
SELECT PartNumberID,PartNumber,BinNumber,Primary FROM 
(
SELECT 
PartNumberID,PartNumber,BinNumber,Primary,
max(primary) over(partition by BinNumber) chk
FROM table
) a
WHERE chk = 0
```

Comment: OK, I had to just cast the BinPrimary as int and both solutions worked. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, This solution will return every row that does not have a BinPrimary whereas the solution from w9lf will only return the BinNumber without having a BinPrimary.